# Google cloud platform load balacing to remove redirect port 8443 from domain name

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, debian, load-balancing

I have a tomcat server with port 8080 which is running on a Google cloud platform VM instance. Also i have enabled SSL for my server. In that i have deployed my web application. When i enter my domain name in browser my application will be running.

But it will be appended with the port 8443. It looks like hostname:8443. By using load balancing in GCP i can able to achieve it. But i am new to GCP so i don't know how to configure and all. Eventhough i have configured but it shows some error like problem with backend service.

Kindly anyone can help me to resolve this.

Comment: Please provide more info about the steps you followed, the error you are getting and any other relevant information that can help us identify the issue. More info can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** about minimal reproducible example policies.

Comment: @sllopis i am getting **1 backend service is unhealthy**. In backend service i have added my port 8443 which is the one appeded in host name. I dont want in my url. In front end configuration by default it takes port 80. 

I just need one confirmation whether i have to add VM instane ip or a load balace produced ip to the domain mapping.

Comment: There are many examples of how to configure load balancers on Google's website, Stackoverflow, Qwiklabs, etc. Go through one of the examples. Then post a question with details on what is going wrong. Just saying help me, does nothing. We need details on how you configured everything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you would like to know whether in the DNS record you need to add VM instance External IP or Load Balancer’s External IP address. If my understanding is correct, in order to use Load Balancer, you need to put the load balancer’s External IP in your DNS A record.

Regarding your 1 backend service is unhealthy, I would request you to check ‘Firewall rules’ section of GCP’s Creating Health Checks [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#firewall_rules). You need to create ingress firewall rules applicable to all VMs being load balanced to allow traffic from health check prober IP ranges. You did mentioned which load balancer you are using. You will find GCP load balancers offering from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview#types_of_cloud_load_balancing). Based on the Load Balancer you are using, you need to create an appropriate heal check firewall rule.

I would recommend posting this type of questions in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) as StackOverflow is for Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers.